# Обратный слеш в php

Tags: php

Установил Php Inspections (EA Extended) v3.0.0 для PHPStorm и вот он мне советует заменить `count($errors[$key])` на `\count($errors[$key])`. Я такого нигде не встречал. Что это и что такое улучшение даёт?

Comment: Это похоже на ссылку на текущее _(относительное)_ пространство имён. Обычно, ссылка ставится перед названием метода или функции, который импортирован в текущий неймспейс.

Comment: Но это же стандартная фукнкция. И в чем тут оптимизация кода?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php я ничего не понял, что-то про пространства имён

Answer (score 4):

1) Если не указывать пространство имен, то функция сначала будет искаться в текущем пространстве имен и только потом в корневом. Чисто теоретически, непосредственное указание пространства имен дает какие-то крохи производительности.

2) Если у вас в пространстве имен присутствует функция с таким-же названием (например strstr), то без явного указания пространства имен будет вызвана именно она, а не функция стандартной библиотеки.

[мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.namespaces.rules.php)

```
namespace A;
foo();      // сперва пытается вызвать "foo", определенную в пространстве имен "A",
            // затем вызывает глобальную функцию "foo"

\foo();     // вызывает функцию "foo", определенную в глобальном пространстве
```

Comment: По этому поводу можно еще добавить про **PHP RFC - Deprecation of fallback to root scope** для 7.3 https://wiki.php.net/rfc/fallback-to-root-scope-deprecation

Comment: @Visman ну это пока только на стадии обсуждения и мне кажется, что не примут, поскольку может сильно поломать обратную совместимость там, где не предусмотрели контроля ошибок (а таких проектов имхо большинство)